# Using python and sqlite3 how do I open a file?

Tags: python, sqlite

I understand how to open a database using a python script:

```
    import sqlite3 as lite
    .
    .
    con = lite.connect(db_name)
```

However what I have is a lot of database files made with tsk_loaddb, when I am in sqlite3 I can use the following

```
    SQLite version 3.8.7.2 2014-11-18 20:57:56
    Enter ".help" for usage hints.
    Connected to a transient in-memory database.
    Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
    sqlite> .open /work/jmjohnso1/db_project/db_IN60-1020
    sqlite> .tables
    blackboard_artifact_types   tsk_files_derived_method
    blackboard_artifacts        tsk_files_path
    blackboard_attribute_types  tsk_fs_info
    blackboard_attributes       tsk_image_info
    tsk_db_info                 tsk_image_names
    tsk_file_layout             tsk_objects
    tsk_files                   tsk_vs_info
    tsk_files_derived           tsk_vs_parts
```

However, I am not understanding how to do it in python. My question is how do I translate the open command with the sqlite3 python library.

Turns out I had a newline in the name because I was reading from a file. So the following works.

```
 def open_sql(db_folder, db_name, table):
        # databases are located at /work/jmjohnso1/db_project  
        path_name = os.path.join(db_folder,db_name).strip()
        con = lite.connect(path_name)
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM ' + table) 
        col_names = [cn[0] for cn in cur.description]
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        print_header(col_names)
        print_output(rows) 
        con.close()
```

Comment: How about `cursor = con.cursor()`, then you can use `cursor` in order to perform operations on your data-base (for example, `cursor.execute(...)`), then you can use the connection itself in order to commit these operations (for example, `con.commit()`)...

Comment: `lite.connect('/work/jmjohnso1/db_project/db_IN60-1020')`

Comment: No that didn't work I changed my question to show what I did.

Comment: D'oh! it was a '/n' problem, I updated my code it works now